# min-height 100% does not extend the full page in WebKit browsers

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
#middle {
  float: right;
  width: 590px;
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

My goal is to get the #middle div to extend all the way to the bottom. This code works perfectly in FF but does not in WebKit browsers. **I've figured out that this is due to the float: right property, without floating, this issue doesn't persist**

In WebKit browsers, it looks like min-height is being deduced and permanently set on the #middle div. This can be viewed by loading the page with the window contracted and then expanding the window to a larger size.

Here is a demo site of the issue: http://staging.similarblue.com/about/beliefs/

I realize I could use some JS to handle this (on window resize) but I was wondering if there's a pure CSS alternative.

Here is a screenshot of the issue: http://i56.tinypic.com/s49e37.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me too, and in Safari, and IE 7/8. :)

Answer (score 1):

<del>Two lines up in your style.css file there's a `height:auto!important` declaration, which is overriding your height:100% declaration.  Without that line, your site looks fine!</del>

What you may be looking for is [this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).  It's served me well in the past, hopefully it helps you!

Comment: I took out this attribute and the page doesn't work if you need to scroll. Go to the portfolio page and you will see.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not quite sure how it applies to me though. Also, they are using the same CSS as I'm using:
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make the background div:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

And then put the content in a separate div *on top* of the fixed background. Here's an example: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fXD6h/)

**EDIT:** accommodated scroll.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure this solution will fit my needs. Specifically because fixed positioning doesn't work as expected on mobile devices (the fixed item actually scrolls because you're moving the viewport). I like this idea though.

Comment: @Mike, ahh unfortunately I have no experience with mobile devices. Wish I could help. Best of luck!